# Cordova/Ionic Android: Conflicting Google Play Services versions between Push and GoogleMaps plugins

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, google-play-services

I am currently developing an Ionic app that requires the [Push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and [GoogleMaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) plugins.

If I create a blank/new project, add android platform,  and install only one of the plugins then everything works perfectly. However, as soon as both plugins are installed, Android won't build.

Here's what I've done so far and is the most basic/simple way to demonstrate the problem:

1. ionic start GoogleServicesIsues blank
2. cd GoogleServicesIssue
3. ionic cordova platforms add android@latest
4. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable
   API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="123"  --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="ABC"
5. ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push  --variable FCM_VERSION=15.0.1
6. ionic cordova build android

...and the build fails as it cannot find the firebase-messaging library.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.1.   Searched in the following locations:
>
> file:/Users/[user]/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/15.0.1/firebase-messaging-15.0.1.jar
>
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/15.0.1/firebase-messaging-15.0.1.pom
>
> ```
>  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/15.0.1/firebase-messaging-15.0.1.jar
> ```
>
> https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/15.0.1/firebase-messaging-15.0.1.pom

Is anyone able to figure out how to get these two plugins to work together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is coming from the `Push` plugin, which lacks a  dependency in the `build.gradle`:

```
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2"
```

^ I have version `17.3.2` there - while you are requesting version `15.0.1`.

... therefore I'd assume, that installing an existing version should fix that:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-push
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable FCM_VERSION=17.3.2
```

version `15.0.1` might rather be correct for the Google Play Services; to be added alike:

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"/>
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"/>
```

if further dependencies should be still missing, just leave a comment below.

Comment: Interesting.  The GoogleMaps plugin will need to be reinstalled with the new version, as well, but this looks promising.

Comment: @NakedBrunch since to new versioning scheme had been introduced, the Firebase and Google Services version numbers may vary... it wasn't always alike this.

Comment: Installing the existing version didn't work.  Explicitly requiring FCM version 17.3.2 is what did the trick.   Thanks for finding this out!

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether this cordova plugin solves your problem. https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release